# Remove junk value from string

Tags: c#, unmanaged

I am getting data from `Device(Time attendance)` using C++ library in C# 4.0, issue is that with name field have some junk value.

Name field is byte array and I had try using `Encoding.Default.GetString(user.Name)`, here user is a Struct.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 48, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi), Serializable]
public struct User
  {
  public int ID; 
  [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 12)]
  public byte[] Name; 
}
```

Output

```
"Jon\0 41 0"
"rakesh\0 6"
```

I want to remove `\0 41 0` and `\0 6`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should be using the `fixed` keyword for the `byte[]`. Then simply use `new string((sbyte*) User.Name)`. See MSDN for the behavior on this.

Comment: Why not declare the field as `String` directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string TrimNullTerminatedString(this string s)
    {
        if (s == null)
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        int i = s.IndexOf('\0');
        if (i >= 0)
            return s.Substring(0, i);
        return s;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
string name = Encoding.Default.GetString(user.Name).TrimNullTerminatedString();
```

---

That being said, a better option would be to handle that at declaration level. If `Name` is a string, there is no reason to declare it as `byte[]`; declare it as a string, and the null terminating character will be handled properly:

```
[MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 12)]
public string Name;
```

It would also be easier to manipulate in code...

Comment: more correct than other answers, but it's better to cut bytes before making string of the array, because some non-trivial encodings (like UTF-8) take more processing and, if I understand right, may even make this method unusable.

Answer (score 1):

RegEx is a best way for removing junk value, In this example with W I remove all character that is not word,

```
textBox1.Text = Regex.Replace("rakesh\0 6", "W", "");
```

You can find complete library for regex on http://regexlib.com/

Comment: Overkill and not efficient. It eliminates only symptom of the error, not the error itself.

Answer (score 0):

do it like this

```
Regex re = New Regex("[\x0A\x0D]", RegexOptions.Compiled)

str = re.Replace(str.Trim(), String.Empty)
```

OR

```
 string str1="";
 for(int i = 0 ; i < str.lengh ; i++) { 
         if(!char.IsLetter(str[i])
              str1 += str[i];
 }

return str1
```

Comment: @Yanshof, thanks for the reply but still no luck. getting same type value.

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with null-terminated strings. So you want to strip zero byte and all bytes after the zero byte in your arrays before passing it to `Encoding.Default.GetString(byte[])`.

## Update:

Example code (may be not very optimal):

```
static byte[] RemoveJunk(byte[] input)
{
    var end = Array.IndexOf(input, (byte)0);
    Console.WriteLine(end);
    if (end < 0)
        return input;
    var result = new byte[end];
    Array.Copy(input, result, end);
    return result;
}
```